# Connecting to Wifi and sharing internet via hotspot in the same time

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, hotspot

As far as I know, it is not possible to connect to Wifi on a Laptop and creating a hotspot (without using a Wireless usb adapter) in the same time. But recently with my friend using his laptop (an old small size HP notebook) he could share the internet on Windows 10 by creating a Hotspot and connecting to the Wifi in the same time.

How is that possible? What kind of technical information do I need to know about this PC, or the Wifi card to explain this?

I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: I have both and if for some reason (internet outage) I am using my Hotspot and then Internet comes back on, wireless will take over even the the Hotspot is connected. They are not both passing traffic at the same. If I need to use my Hotpost to test VPN, I must disconnect my wireless to be sure.

Comment: Check this thread - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84440/hotspot-and-internet-access-together-why-not